# How do I know that an "Orthodox" theological work is officially Orthodox doctrine?

Tags: eastern-orthodox

Whenever I read theological works written by Roman Catholics I know that, as long as there is an "*Imprimatur*" from a legitimate Bishop, I can trust it to be official Catholic doctrine.

On the other hand, whenever I read contemporary Eastern Orthodox writings, I'm not 100% sure how to tell whether or not its trustworthy, or simply rogue theological opinion.

So far I've been clinging to anything recommended by St. Vladimir's Orthodox Seminary.

Comment: An imprimatur from a legitimate Catholic bishop does not ensure that the work is official Catholic doctrine; it only ensures that the work doesn't contradict official Catholic doctrine.  So such a work could express opinions on questions that the Church has not officially decided.

Comment: In my previous comment, "it only ensures" should have been "it only intends to ensure".  Even legitimate Catholic bishops might occasionally make a mistake.

Comment: Can you provide an example from a specific source as to where this has ever happened? That would be interesting...

Comment: No, I don't know specific examples.  I added the second comment because I feared that my first comment sounded like a claim that an imprimatur is infallible, and I wouldn't want to make such a claim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official Orthodox doctrine is covered by *Orthodox Dogmatics*. The good book on it is [Orthodox dogmatic theology](http://www.intratext.com/IXT/ENG0824/) by protopresbyter *Michael Pomazansky*. All except written in the book, could not be treated as a real *Orthodox Doctrine*, but only as intepretations.

There are no `simply rogue theological opinion` in Orthodoxy, except that is condamned as a heresy on Councils: ecumenical, or local. There are the opinions that can talk about some things in *Orthodox Dogmatics*, that inagree with the main course, but not declared as a heresy. They called as *individual theologic opinion*.

One yet is. St. Nilus of Sinai said (in my retell): *"We have the Creed, and for laic people it is enough to trust just in it"*.